# Redirect output into multiple files

Tags: python, file, automation

I have a script in that script we have multiple hostnames and trying to print the command of the output into multiple files i.e each hostname has different output, want to print that in multiple files.

I have the code that is printing all output in a single txt file, Please find the attached code below.

```
 from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import getpass
import sys
from datetime import datetime


passwd = getpass.getpass('Please enter the password: ')

my_devices = ['192.1.1.1', '192.1.1.2', '192.1.1.3'] 
device_list = list() 

for device_ip in my_devices:
    device = {
        "device_type": "cisco_ios",
        "host": device_ip,
        "username": "root",
        "password": passwd, # Log in password from getpass
        "secret": passwd # Enable password from getpass
    }
    device_list.append(device)

print(device_list) #list of dictionaries

for each_device in device_list:
    connection = ConnectHandler(**each_device)
    connection.enable()
    print(f'Connecting to {each_device["host"]}')
    output = connection.send_command('show configuration | display set')
    sys.stdout = open((datetime.today()).strftime('%Y%m%d')+ "_" + "switch_config.txt", 'a')
    print(output)

    print(f'Closing Connection on {each_device["host"]}')
    connection.disconnect()
```

Comment: And ...? Where do the multiple files come into play?

Comment: Three host switch has three different output, I don't have three output in the same file, I need three different output in three different file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `open` another file for each.

```
for each_device in device_list:
    connection = ConnectHandler(**each_device)
    connection.enable()
    print(f'Connecting to {each_device["host"]}')
    output = connection.send_command('show configuration | display set')
    with open((datetime.today()).strftime('%Y%m%d')+ "_" + each_device["host"] + "_switch_config.txt", 'a') as filehandle:
        filehandle.write(output + "\n")
    print(f'Closing Connection on {each_device["host"]}')
    connection.disconnect()
```

This avoids the ugly messing with `sys.stdout` (which would also write your diagnostic messages to  the file, obviously) and you didn't reveal what the file should be called and whether or not it should be overwritten, so I had to guess.